# CSS not loading through verify account or reset password link C#

Tags: c#, html, css

I'm sending a link to my e-mail and when I click, it correctly loads the page, but it doesn't load the CSS in this page. I'm not allowed to post images yet, sorry for the links to them.

[How the page is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcxwg.jpg) 
[How the view.html was like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToXxk.png)

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "VerifyAccount";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Verify Account</h2>
```

Then I tried to link all the references I have on my _Layout, it sort of worked, but it's not loading the fonts nor the logo image where I circled red:
[Added styles into the view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCtDZ.png)

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Verificação de Conta";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - GarotasGamers.gg</title>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<!-- Google Font -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/flaticon.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/slicknav.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/main.css")" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css" />
</head>
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
```

[Circled where the logo was supposed to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aTWj.png)

It seems as if the document is not able to load the references on the project when it's coming to style. Other links as such go to login pages are working fine.

Comment: Pictures of your code are not helpful. You can edit the code directly into your question.

Comment: did as suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the developer tools to see if the css files are at the correct url?

Try using the @URL.Content helper in your head:

```
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/main.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Sure, I'll try in a bit.

Comment: I'm getting 404 error in developer tools for all the style links I tried to reference. The urls seem to be correct, all under /Content

Comment: If you get a 404 that means they are not found. Try playing with the target link for one of the files that are giving a 404.

Comment: The link is like /UserAccount/Content/style.css, as a sample, it indeed doesn't exists. The contents aren't in /UserAccount.
They are simply in /Content/style.css, and that's how I'm linking them on my view, <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: for other pages under /UserAccount, all the references are being correctly loaded, except for these two that I'm accessing through the link in my email. Now only the logo that comes from /Shared/_Layout isn't loading

Comment: I see, the css definition of the url(../../) is not relative. Make a separate test page and separate css file with url inks with various forms of relative paths. Whichever one works is how you have to specify the relative urls in your css. Good luck!

Comment: I referenced the path where the images are, with all the references as you suggested (href="@Url.Content...), it worked, now it loads both css and logo images. thanks.